# How to select variable and class together in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization

How to select variable and class together in jQuery?

My code:

```
var galeryBox = $(".galeryBox .nivo-controlNav .nivo-control");

$(galeryBox).hide();

$(".thumbLeft").hide();
```

I would like to use `hide()` only once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) for that. `add()`, well *adds*, collections or elements to the current collection:

```
$(".thumbLeft").add(galeryBox).hide();
```